# How can I validate first number not zero in vue?

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

My code like this :

```
<v-text-field
   type="number"
   v-model="text" @input="text = text.replace(/^0/g, '');" 
>
```

Demo and full code like this : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/vYYPrEq?editors=1010

This code is works. But I can input 00000. It shouldn't be

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a handler to slove the issue. My solution [here](https://codepen.io/tuhin47/pen/vYYPMpV?editors=1010)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
       <v-text-field
          type="number"
           @keyup="handler(text)"
            v-model="text"
        >
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Apparently your code has not worked perfectly. If I enter `852`. Then I move the cursor to the right of the number `8` and enter the number `0`, it can. So your code isn't perfect

Comment: you can add extra validation. If the length greater then 1 then the initial character should not be `0`